# Encryption of data between Mac application and PHP application

Tags: php, security, macos, encryption

I am new to the whole encryption world, and I wish to build a Mac application which interacts with a PHP application in order to access and manipulate data remotely.
My problem is that I can't just transfer plain data over the internet, as most of the data being transfered can be very private, as well as username and password are passed for authentication of the user.

I would like to know what kind of encryption/decryption methods I need to use in order the data will be transfered safely over the internet.

Shillo.

Comment: I would think you just need to use a secure connection as far as the transmission is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to use is SSL with HTTPS.  This is well supported by just about any system and HTTP library.  No additional encryption is typically necessary.

To do this, you simply need to purchase an SSL certificate and install it on your web server.  You can generate one on your own for free, but a certificate authenticated by a 3rd party is often preferred.

Comment: "but a certificate authenticated by a 3rd party is often preferred." --- it does, when client application can check if the certificate was created by some well-known company (like all modern browser do). In case of 2 custom application - it is just wasting of money.

Comment: Thank you. I assume I should create my own SSL certificate?

Comment: That is the free option.  Unless you plan on having browser-visible pages on this server, that is fine.  If users will be visiting it with a web browser, they will get a warning stating that the certificate authority is not trusted.

Comment: It's basically a third party extension to a CMS, and I do not wish to force SSL on the entire site or the administration panel, only for specific pages in the website. Is such picky behavior possible to achieve with SSL?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this extension was not meant to be accessible through a browser, so I don't mind people receive warning when trying to access those secured resources.

Comment: Just add the SSL certificate for HTTPS and keep your regular HTTP running as well.  This is very common.